# issue with trigger in ms sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, ssis

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'myTrigger' AND type = 'TR')
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER myTrigger
END
GO
go
create trigger myTrigger
on mytable_backup
instead of insert
as
begin
  declare @seq int
  select @seq = seq from inserted 
  if exists (select * from mytable_backup where seq= @seq) begin
      delete from mytable_backup where seq=@seq
  end
  insert into mytable_backup
  select * from inserted
end
go
```

I've written this trigger to check while inserting if `seq` column is repeated then update the previous row with same `seq` if `seq` doesn't exits insert it with new `seq`.

In ssis package I'm using OLEDB table(`Mytable`) as a source which contains.

```
Name,Age,Seq
Gauraw,30,1
Gauraw,31,1
Kiran,28,3
Kiran,29,3
kiran,28,3
Venkatesh,,4
Venkatesh,28,4
```

Now I'm loading this table to OLEDB destination(`Mytable_backup`) as destination.
I suppose to get output as.

```
Gauraw,31,1
kiran,28,3
Venkatesh,28,4
```

But I'm getting all the records from `Mytable` into `Mytable_backup`.

is anything wrong with my trigger?

Comment: Triggers, like most SQL operations, operate on sets.  Yours assumes only one row will be inserted at a time.  This does not bode well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this trigger will just take the first row and compare it with the existing. If I understand what you want to do you can quit easy do this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'myTrigger' AND type = 'TR')
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER myTrigger
END
GO
go
create trigger myTrigger
on mytable_backup
instead of insert
as
begin
insert into mytable_backup
select 
    * 
from 
    inserted
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            mytable_backup AS mytable
        WHERE
            inserted.seq=mytable.seq
    )
end
go
```

**EDIT**

So I found out what was going on. If you insert all of the rows in one go the `inserted` contains all the rows.. Sorry my mistake. If there are duplicates in your data your example do not show which to choose. I have chosen the one with the maximum of age (don't know what your requirements is). Here is a update with the full example

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_backup
(
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Age INT,
    Seq INT
)
GO
```

**Trigger**

```
create trigger myTrigger
on mytable_backup
instead of insert
as
begin
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY inserted.Seq ORDER BY Age) AS RowNbr,
        inserted.*
    FROM
        inserted
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            mytable_backup
        WHERE
            mytable_backup.Seq=inserted.Seq
    )
)
insert into mytable_backup(Age,Name,Seq)
SELECT
    CTE.Age,
    CTE.Name,
    cte.Seq
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
end
GO
```

**Insert of test data**

```
INSERT INTO mytable_backup
VALUES
    ('Gauraw',30,1),
    ('Gauraw',31,1),
    ('Kiran',28,3),
    ('Kiran',29,3),
    ('kiran',28,3),
    ('Venkatesh',20,4),
    ('Venkatesh',28,4)

SELECT * FROM mytable_backup
```

**Drop of the database objects**

```
DROP TRIGGER myTrigger
DROP TABLE mytable_backup
```

Comment: still getting all the rows from `mytable` into `mytable_backup`

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look

Answer (score 1):

Your original code has two flaws:

1. It assumes that only one record is inserted at a time.
2. Your insert into mytable_backup happens outside of the if condition.  That insert will execute every time.